# Outputting data from for loop to .mat file using numbers in title MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, save

I need to output .mat files for the below data. I need one file to have cell (1,1) to be Mean_RPM_list1, cell (2,1) to be Mean_RPM_list2 etc. And then I need another file to have cell(1,1) to be Mean_Torque_list1 to have cell(1,1).....and so on.

Can anybody shed any light on this for me?
Also if someone knows how to automate me calling the matrices A and B so I could have A = [Mean_rpm1:Mean_rpmMAX], that would also be very helpful.

TIA for any help.

```
A = [Mean_rpm1 Mean_rpm2 Mean_rpm3 Mean_rpm4 Mean_rpm5 Mean_rpm6 Mean_rpm7 Mean_rpm8 Mean_rpm9 Mean_rpm10 Mean_rpm11 Mean_rpm12];

B = [Mean_torque1 Mean_torque2 Mean_torque3 Mean_torque4 Mean_torque5 Mean_torque6 Mean_torque7 Mean_torque8 Mean_torque9 Mean_torque10 Mean_torque11 Mean_torque12];

plot(A,B,'*')


for i = 1:num_bins;
  bin = first + ((i-1)/10);
  eval(sprintf('Mean_RPM_list%0.f = A;',bin*10));
  eval(sprintf('Mean_Torque_list%0.f = B;',bin*10));  
end
```

Comment: Could you try to frame the question a bit more clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this is really bad idea to create a set of variables with names different by numbers. As you can see it's very difficult to deal with such variables, you always have to use eval (or other related) statements.

It's much easier to create a cell array Mean_rpm and access its elements as Mean_rpm{1}, etc.

If the vectors are numeric and have the same size you can also make a 2D/3D array. Then access as Mean_rpm(:,:,1) etc.

Next, to store a cell array to a mat-file you have to create this array in MATLAB. No options (at least for now) to do it by parts in a loop. (But you can do it for numeric vectors and matrices using matfile object.) So why do you need this intermediate Mean_RPM_list variable? Just do `Mean_RPM_list{bin*10} = A` in your loop.

For your first question, if you already have those variables you have to use eval in a loop. Something like

```
A = [];
for k=1:K
    eval(sprintf('A{k} = [A, Mean_rpm%d];',k));
end
```

You can also get names for all similar variables and combine them.

```
varlist = who('Mean_rpm*');
A = cell(1,numel(varlist);
for k = 1:numel(varlist)
    eval('A{k} = varlist{k};');
end
```

Here is one without loop using CELL2FUN:

```
A=cellfun(@(x)evalin('base',x),varlist,'UniformOutput',0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid having all these individual variables around in the first place. Data types like arrays, cell arrays and structure arrays exist to help you with this. If you want each variable to be associated with a name, you can use a structure array. I've made an example below. Instead of assigning a value to `Mean_rpm1` like you are doing now, assign it to `meanStruct.Mean_rpm1` then save the entire structure.

```
% as you generate values for each variable, assign them to the
% appropriate field.
meanStruct.Mean_rpm1 = [10:10];
meanStruct.Mean_rpm2 = [12:15];
meanStruct.Mean_rpm3 = [13:20];
meanStruct.Mean_rpm4 = [14];
meanStruct.Mean_rpm5 = [15:18];
meanStruct.Mean_rpm6 = [16:20];
meanStruct.Mean_rpm7 = [17:22];
meanStruct.Mean_rpm8 = [18:22];
meanStruct.Mean_rpm9 = [19:22];
meanStruct.Mean_rpm10 = [20:22];
meanStruct.Mean_rpm11 = [21:22];
meanStruct.Mean_rpm12 = [22:23];

% save the structure array
save('meanValues.mat','meanStruct')


% load and access the structure array
clear all
load('meanValues.mat')
temp = meanStruct.Mean_rpm3
```